# Creating a heatmap from Mortality Data?

Tags: r, heatmap

I have two formats of my Mortality Data, one in the list form you get it from The Human Mortality Database, with Male, Female and Combined data all in columns. The other format is separated into Male and Female matrices, with just Age, year and the mortality rate in each matrix.

The first format is along the lines of

```
Year Age   Female     Male    Total  
1961  99     0.3       0.4     0.3  
1961  98     0.4       0.5     0.4
```

etc.

The second format I separated to get data in the form of:

```
 Age 1961  1962  1963 .....  
  0  0.02  0.02  0.02 ...  
  1  0.002 0.002 0.002....
```

etc.

I would like to be able to plot a heatmap so I can look at the cohort effects etc.

I have tried various methods found by searching online but these aren't working for the way my data is presented. The heatmaps I've produced come out completely red. Can anyone help?

I've tried this:

```
rnames <- France[,1]   #assign labels in column 1 to "rnames"
mat_data <- data.matrix(France[,2:ncol(France)])
rownames(mat_data) <- rnames #assign row names
col_breaks = c(seq(-1,0,length=100),  # for red
  seq(0,0.8,length=100),              # for yellow
  seq(0.8,1,length=100))              # for green
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "green"))(n = 299)
png("location",    # create PNG for the heat map        
  width = 5*300,        # 5 x 300 pixels
  height = 5*300,
  res = 300,            # 300 pixels per inch
  pointsize = 8)        # smaller font size

heatmap.2(mat_data,
cellnote=mat_data,
main="Correlation",
notecol="black",
trace="none",
margins =c(12,9),
col=my_palette,
breaks=col_breaks,
dendrogram="row",
Colv="NA")
dev.off()
```

Which creates a solid red heatmap, with the year listed along the bottom, and then the word Age next to the years, and then the actual ages listed along the y-axis. It also gives me an error code:

```
Error in seq.default(min.raw, max.raw, by = min(diff(breaks)/4)) : 
invalid (to - from)/by in seq(.)
```

Does anyone know of a better way of producing the heatmap or what I've done wrong here?

Comment: Please read up on [ask] and how to create a [reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This includes (some) data, preferebly the output of a call to dput, and your own code.

Comment: @Heroka I wasn't sure what to include since all the code that I'd tried was really long and failed so much?

Comment: We need to see at least an example of the data, and what you've tried. If things are failing, we need to see where and what the error is.

Comment: @Emma at least some data is needed. If it's a lot of code you've already tried you don't need to post all of it of course, but maybe the most recent try?

Comment: @Heroka I've included my closest attempt now, I'll shortly include a sample of the data! Not sure what's allowed due to copyright laws etc. though

Comment: Which line is breaking it? R doesn't like one of your `seq` functions, but the three I see here work fine on my end. Is there one in the code that's not shown?

Comment: @Emma you may also post simulated data, if copyright is a concern. If you do so, make sure that types/variable names match.

Comment: And do you have an example of the output you have in mind?

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 it's the `Colv="NA"`  line, it takes my `seq` functions ok I think

Comment: @Heroka http://momentumpublishing.co.uk/weknow0.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Heat-map-cohort-path.jpg similar to this

Comment: So you don't need the dendrogram your code currently produces?

Comment: @EmmaThomas it's the `Colv="NA"` line because that's the end of the function call to `heatmap.2`, therefore the error is in one of the args passed to the function... one of the many, many args passed :-)

Comment: @Heroka not really, more was just following the code at the time. I'll take that bit out!

Comment: @Heroka turns out I can't just remove it! what should that bit be instead?

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 so what should I do sorry? Pretty new to R so this is all confusing to me!

Comment: @Emma your expected output has an x-axis for year and an y-axis for age, so to me it looks quite different from the plot your code produces (with the columns)

Comment: @EmmaThomas what is in your `France` frame?

Comment: @Heroka I know! That's what the problem is! I have no idea how to do what I'm trying to get to!

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 the first table I gave, I've also tried it for the second table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this in any way helpful? I based it on what your data looks like, and generated some data to match. 
Then I started with a plot with 'year' on the x-axis and 'age' on the y-axis and a square (geom_tile) for each point. Those squares are coloured according to the 'total'. It doesn't have any polygons like the example you gave, but I think with your real data it would enable you to look for cohort effects.

```
#generate some data ranging from 0 to 0.1
set.seed(1000)
France <- expand.grid(Year=1961:2000,Age=20:98)
France$Female <- runif(nrow(France),0,0.05)
France$Male <- runif(nrow(France),0,0.05)
France$Total <- France$Male + France$Female


library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(France, aes(x=Year,y=Age,fill=Total)) + 
  geom_tile()+ 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rainbow(10))
p1
```

[image]

Comment: ok, so I tried running the code for my data but it says `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'year' not found` , is the year coming from my data? I tried `France$year` and the same for age and total but it comes up with `Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) :   argument "env" is missing, with no default`, do you know what this means?

Comment: It means I'm sloppy with capitalization. Will fix (I used variable names without capitals).

Comment: oh but that is exactly what I'm wanting though!

Comment: that's working beautifully now, thank you! What are the options with the colour scheme, it's coming out very red due to most mortality rates being between 0 and 0.1! Guess there's not a lot you can do about that though. It seems that the 0-0.1 is red as well as above 0.45?

Comment: My mistake, I used a wrong call to `scale_gradientn` based on another solution-idea (which was false). You can play around with it, use different colours.

Comment: If it works for you, could you accept it? Keeps others from spending time on it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [source code](https://github.com/cran/gplots/blob/master/R/heatmap.2.R#L644):

```
z <- seq(min.raw, max.raw, by=min(diff(breaks)/4))
```

The `heatmap.2` code is internally calling the `seq` function and produces the error you're experiencing:

```
Error in seq.default(min.raw, max.raw, by = min(diff(breaks)/4)) : 
    invalid (to - from)/by in seq(.)
```

What are `min.raw` and `max.raw`, though? Scroll up a bit (line 640) and you'll see they are the min and max of the `breaks` arg you passed in (which in this case is -1 and 1 respectively). The `by` parameter in the internal `seq` function evaluates to 0:

```
min(diff(breaks)/4)
```

In fact, you can replicate this error if you try to construct a `seq` function with these parameters:

```
> seq(-1, 1, by=0)
Error in seq.default(-1, 1, by = 0) : invalid (to - from)/by in seq(.)
```

There are two implications here: first of all, you've uncovered a cornercase that breaks that code and this is a bug that should probably be reported on the [github repository](https://github.com/cran/gplots) (i.e., if this evaluates to 0, use some pre-defined `by` param). Secondly, you *could* use a uniform `break` parameter or just not define it. It is, afterall, an optional parameter. From the documentation:

```
breaks
(optional) Either a numeric vector indicating the splitting points for binning x
into colors, or a integer number of break points to be used, in which case the break
points will be spaced equally between min(x) and max(x).
```

By leaving `breaks` blank or providing a single value, you shouldn't encounter this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, when you say leaving `breaks` blank what do you mean exactly? do I set the `breaks=0` ,leave it blank or remove it? Or something entirely?

Comment: Just remove `breaks=col_breaks` from the call entirely. So it would be: `heatmap.2(mat_data,
cellnote=mat_data,
main="Correlation",
notecol="black",
trace="none",
margins =c(12,9),
col=my_palette,
dendrogram="row",
Colv="NA")` Give that a try and see what happens.

Comment: There isn't any output anymore? I tried doing `p <- heatmap.2(mat_data,
cellnote=mat_data,
main="Correlation",
notecol="black",
trace="none",
margins =c(12,9),
col=my_palette,
dendrogram="row",
Colv="NA")`
And then doing `p` but it just comes up with lots of numbers!